# AdSense - Refresh page on making changes

Tags: adsense

It's a violation of the Google Adsense TOS to refresh the page several times because I have to try out changes on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?hl=en

> Clicks on Google ads must result from genuine user interest. Any
>   method that artificially generates clicks or impressions on your
>   Google ads is strictly prohibited. These prohibited methods include,
>   but are not limited to, repeated manual clicks or impressions,
>   automated click and impression generating tools and the use of robots
>   or deceptive software. Please note that clicking your own ads for any
>   reason is prohibited.

Can't you turn off Adsense while you are testing changes? Or at least turn them off in your development enviroment.

Or, you could add a rule not to show them when your ip visits the site.

Comment: ofcourse, If you comment the code, the Adsense will not load.

Comment: I can also create an identical page without ads just for testing right? I could be the only one who knows the url.

Comment: sure, that would be no problem. Just be sure that no one ever knows about this page and that Google doesn't index it.